# Find difference between two comma separated NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsmutablestring

Suppose I have two `NSMutableString` like this:-

`String` 1 -----   {aaa,bss,cdd,dff,eee,fgh}

`String` 2 -----   {aaa,bss,cdd}

How can we find the the difference between `String` 1 & `String` 2 in an `NSArray`:-

Like this:-  { dff,eee,fgh  }

As mentioned in duplicate question it is different.

Comment: Does string includes `{` curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both these strings in two different NSMutableSets and then subtract 2nd from 1st.
You will have your result.

```
NSString* str1 = @"aaa,bss,cdd,dff,eee,fgh";
NSString* str2 = @"aaa,bss,cdd";

NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

[set1 minusSet:set2];

NSLog(@"result %@",[set1 allObjects]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `NSMutableArray` to remove same objects.

For Eg.

```
NSString *s1 = @"aaa,bss,cdd,dff,eee,fgh";
NSString *s2 = @"aaa,bss,cdd";

NSArray *arr1 = [s1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *arr2 = [s2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSMutableArray *resArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr1];
[resArray removeObjectsInArray:arr2];

NSString *res = [resArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Result :: %@", res);
```

Answer (score 0):

First part of the problem is to separate each string into substrings separated by the commas.

To create the substrings you can use

`[string substringFromIndex:index]` - to get an NSString from that index foward
`[string substringToIndex:index]` - to get an NSString from the begining to that index
Or you could combine it into 
`[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(fisrtIndex, secondIndex)]` - to get a strin from the first index to the second index

Those are the basic operations. But there are a lot more in this case you could use specifically:

`[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` to get an NSArray with all the substrings. That would have the problem of the `'{'` and `'}'` appearing in the first and last component. This can be solved in many ways:

- by first trimming the string using the substring methods already explained
- by using another method altogether

`[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",{"]]` The problem with this method is, because your strings start/end with one of the separators you would get the first/last component an empty string. You can just remove it from the array or ignore it or choose the other method, your choice.

Now that you know how to get the substrings all you need to know is how to compare the two. There are literally many ways to do this. I am just going to name a few. Of course each solution has its own advantages and disadvantages and code complexity.

1 - comparing each substring one by one the the other using `isEqualToString:`

2 - comparing each substring from one of the original strings with the full second original string by using `[string2 rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound`

3 - if you have iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite you can use `[string2 containsString:substring]`

4 - You can transform the arrays of substrings into sets and then compare them as Ankit Srivastava suggested

5 - You can use the `removeObjectsInArray` to get the substrings that are not common between the two and then use that newly created array to `removeObjectsInArray` to the original and have just the common...

Really the possibilities are almost endless